# For Loop Only Iterating Once

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm using the pyvmomi module to export data from our vCenter. I'm very close to getting the desired output, but my script is only iterating through once. Why?

If I `print(d)` in the `for` loop before updating the dictionary, it will print all of the data.

**Script Summary:**

```
top_dict = {"data": []}    

def get_obj(content, vimtype, name=None):
    return [item for item in content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
        content.rootFolder, [vimtype], recursive=True).view]

## MAIN ##
...
content = si.RetrieveContent()
d = {}
idnum = 0
for dc in get_obj(content, vim.Datacenter):
    for cluster in get_obj(content, vim.ClusterComputeResource):
        for h in cluster.host:
            host_wwpn1 = ''
            for adaptr in h.config.storageDevice.hostBusAdapter:
                if hasattr(adaptr, 'portWorldWideName'):
                    if host_wwpn1 == '':
                        host_wwpn1 = (hex(adaptr.portWorldWideName)[2:18])
                    else:
                        host_wwpn2 = (hex(adaptr.portWorldWideName)[2:18])
            d['id'] = idnum
            d['datacenter'] = dc.name
            d['cluster'] = cluster.name
            d['host'] = h.name
            d['pwwn_F1'] = host_wwpn1
            d['pwwn_F2'] = host_wwpn2
            idnum = idnum + 1
    top_dict.update({"data": [d]})
```

**Current Output:**

```
{
  "data": [
       {
        "id": 0,
        "datacenter": "MY_DATACENTER",
        "cluster": "MY_CLUSTER",
        "host": "MY_HOSTNAME",
        "pwwn_F1": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "pwwn_F2": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your issue is on the very last line of the code you've shown. That line replaces the entire contents of the `top_dict` with new values. I'm pretty sure you want to be adding your new dictionary `d` to the list that's inside of `top_dict`.

Instead, I think you want to be doing `top_dict["data"].append(d)`. You will also need to move the initialization of `d` at the same level as the `append` call (so probably between the first two loops, if you keep the last line indented as it is now).

I'm not sure if that last line is indented the correct amount or not (since I don't actually know what your code is supposed to do). Currently, you might set the values in `d` several times before using them. You may want to indent the last line to be at the same level as the lines setting values in `d` (the initialization of `d` should then also be at that level too).

Comment: You are correct! I placed my dict `d` and put `top_dict["data"].append(d)` right after my last `for` loop and it works beautifully. @Blckknght thank you for your help.